# Usage of “Want someone to do something” in relative

Tags: relative-clauses

Should i use pronoun “him” before “ to win “secondly in relative clauses in sentence below ?

“ The man who i want to win award “.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase lacks an an article before "award". It can be:

- The man who I want to win an/the award
- The man that I want to win an/the award
- The man I want to win an/the award

You don't need the pronoun "him" because the relative pronoun "who/that" substitutes for it.

Please note that, to be a sentence, a main clause would be necessary:

- I'd like you to meet the man who I want to win an/the award.
- The man that I want to win an/the award does not want to participate in the contest.
- This is the man I want to win an/the award.

Comment: Also possible: "The man **whom** I want to win an/the award."  This is the most formally correct version since "whom" properly replaces "him," although in casual speech many native speakers will use "who" and perhaps even regard "whom" as oddly formal.